# How to apply css with OpenStreetMap and OpenLayers

Tags: css, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm trying to use OpenLayers with OpenStreetMap. My map is printed, ok, but I have the copyright line in the middle of the map. Why? I would like to have it at the bottom. Red color is applied but not bottom, why and how to do, please?

```css
.olControlAttribution {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0em;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">

<div id="OpenLayers_Control_Attribution_7" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1004;" class="olControlAttribution olControlNoSelect" unselectable="on">
  © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add a complete code snippet? because with your example the DIV is rendered on the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how to do? .css is big and StackoverFlow say to me "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." I can't write as much as css...

Comment: In these cases I've seen some questions that offer a public acces to their codes. Maybe if you have an URL to check your HTML/CSS would be easier to solve.

Comment: Well, I was inspired by the page http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/drag-feature.html with 26 rules css (see source)

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you without your exact source. I can position the .OpenLayers_Control_Attribution_7 in the example easily.

Comment: Yes, you helped :)
I still don't know why my .olControlAttribution didn't worked but #OpenLayers_Control_Attribution_7 solved the solution. Thanks ;)

Comment: That's probable because a CSS property is more important when you use and ID than when you use a class name. In the worst case scenario use "!important" to totally override a property. For example: "color: red !important;"

Comment: ok thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Raul who helped me:)

If my .olControlAttribution didn't worked, #OpenLayers_Control_Attribution_7 solved the solution.